# не работает код при клике на $plus выдает не то

Tags: javascript

**Есть код**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
// скрипт выбора колличества продукта 
$services = $('.services__btn_span');
$minus = $('.services_minus');
$nomer = $('.services_nomer');
$plus = $('.services_plus');

$minus.click(function(){
    $result = $('#services_nomer').text();
    $finish = $result - 1;
    $('#services_nomer').text($finish);
});
$plus.click(function(){
    $result = $('#services_nomer').text();
    $finish = $result + 1;
    $('#services_nomer').text($finish);
});
```

});

[image: первое изображение нажимаю на минус, отнимается число, на второй картинке нажимаешь на плюс, он не прибавляет а добавляет число, что не так??]

Comment: при нажатии кнопки минус, число отнимается, при нажатии плюс, становится не 2 как должно быть 1+1, а 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js при считывания значения позиционирует его как стоку, а при суммировании с ней конвертирует единицу в сточку, попробуйте

```
$plus.click(function(){
    $result = $('#services_nomer').text();
    $finish = parseInt($result) + 1;
    $('#services_nomer').text($finish);
});
```

либо другой метод, так как text() возвращает именно сроку